# Redacted Iterator in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am going through a Ruby course on Codecademy.com. The problem is listed under Iterators and Loops. Here are the instructions:

Let's start simple: write an .each loop that goes through words and just prints out each word it finds.

Here is what I have which does not seem to pass the test, so I just want to know if it is correct or not.

```
puts "need input please"
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")
words.each do |x|
  puts "#{x}"
end

puts "need another input"
redact = gets.chomp
```

Somewhat oddly, this is what passed the course example

```
puts "need input please"
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ") 
redact = gets.chomp
```

Which is obcviously not right since it does not make use of the `.each` loop.

Comment: *Here is what I have which does not seem to pass the test* --- Why are you thinking so? It does pass the test.

Comment: because the evaluator gives me an error saying I did it wrong, so I am basically looking to see if I did do this wrong because I think it is correct.

Comment: Note x is a string already, so `puts x` is sufficient.

Comment: I would contact them about a potential bug.

Comment: I posted it in the forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words.each do |x|
  puts "#{x}"
end
```

`x` is your block variable, and doesn't need to be interpolated.

Try

```
words.each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Comment: While I agree that this works, I am going to be eternally sad if this is the reason it is breaking.

Comment: it said I was wrong, but given the fact that the code I know is wrong passed I'm going to mark yours as correct

Answer (score 0):

hello im doing the same course on codecademy and wrote this even though it lets me pass im unsure if its correct if this helps

```
puts "Enter paragraph here: "
text=gets.chomp
puts "Word to redact"
redact = gets.chomp
words = text.split {" "}
words.each do |words|

  if words == redact
    print "REDACTED "
  else 
    print words + " "
  end
end
```